# animate back and forth with svg/smil (NOT CSS)

Tags: svg, smil

How would you set up a svg animateTransform to rotate an arrow back and forth infinitely, slowing down as it reaches its extremities? (like a pendulum).

Looking at the spec there is an attribute called autoReverse - https://www.w3.org/TR/SMIL3/smil-timemanip.html#TimeManip-autoReverseSyntax - but it doesn't work and perhaps has not been implemented anywhere.

I want the rotating element to repeat going back and forth forever, rotating around the centrepoint of the circles, like in the example below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 701.09 165.13">
    <circle cx="347.37" cy="177.35" r="35.19" fill="#e4e7ea" stroke-width="0" />
    <circle cx="347.37" cy="177.35" r="31.52" transform="translate(94.42 474.22) rotate(-76.61)"
        fill="#edf1f4" stroke-width="0" />
    <path d="m348.28,113.8c-.2-1.09-1.63-1.09-1.84,0l-4.56,35.94,5.48,17.44,5.48-17.44-4.56-35.94Z"
        fill="#373838" stroke-width="0">
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" to="-45 347.37 177.35" from="45 347.37 177.35" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
        accelerate=".5" decelerate=".5" autoReverse="true" />

    </path>
    <circle cx="347.37" cy="177.35" r="17.72" transform="translate(94.66 474.42) rotate(-76.66)"
        fill="#fff" stroke-width="0" />
    <path
        d="m347.37,195.96c-10.27,0-18.62-8.35-18.62-18.62s8.35-18.62,18.62-18.62,18.62,8.35,18.62,18.62-8.35,18.62-18.62,18.62Zm0-35.45c-9.28,0-16.83,7.55-16.83,16.83s7.55,16.83,16.83,16.83,16.83-7.55,16.83-16.83-7.55-16.83-16.83-16.83Z"
        fill="#373838" stroke-width="0" />
</svg>
```

I build the basic shape in Illustrator and then opened the SVG in a text editor and started copying and pasting the numbers into the animateTransform from and to until it worked. I don't really understand the numbers other than figuring they are x and y coordinates. I certainly have no clue about how curves work, even after watching bezier explainer videos. So don't math at me.

I've seen various mentions of "keytimes" and "splines" (the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#KeyTimesAttribute) of which is effectively meaningless gibberish to me).

Any thoughts / simple explanations appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much benefit in reading the SMIL specification. If you want to find out what is implemented in browsers, read  [SVG animations](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations). Despite the "draft" status, for now it is more or less the same as the [Animation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html) chapter in SVG 1.1 and has only minor differences to existing implementations.

`accelerate`, `decelerate` and `autoReverse` are all not part of SVG animations. To reverse an animation, you have to define a forth-and-back movement. Instead of defining `from` and `to`, define a `values` list, each value separated with a semicolon. Add to that a `keyTimes` list with exactly the same number of entries, the first one 0, the last one 1, and all others inbetween as relative times, just like the percentage values in CSS keyframes animations.

Define the interpolation mode with `calcMode="spline"` and define the splines to use for each movement from frame to frame as a list with `keySplines`. The number of entries, again separated with a semicolon, must be exactly one less than the number of `values` and of `keyTimes`.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 701.09 165.13">
    <circle cx="347.37" cy="177.35" r="35.19" fill="#e4e7ea" stroke-width="0" />
    <circle cx="347.37" cy="177.35" r="31.52" transform="translate(94.42 474.22) rotate(-76.61)"
        fill="#edf1f4" stroke-width="0" />
    <path d="m348.28,113.8c-.2-1.09-1.63-1.09-1.84,0l-4.56,35.94,5.48,17.44,5.48-17.44-4.56-35.94Z"
        fill="#373838" stroke-width="0">
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate"
        values="45 347.37 177.35;
               -45 347.37 177.35;
                45 347.37 177.35"
        keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="spline"
        keySplines=".7 0 .3 1;.7 0 .3 1"
        dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />

    </path>
    <circle cx="347.37" cy="177.35" r="17.72" transform="translate(94.66 474.42) rotate(-76.66)"
        fill="#fff" stroke-width="0" />
    <path
        d="m347.37,195.96c-10.27,0-18.62-8.35-18.62-18.62s8.35-18.62,18.62-18.62,18.62,8.35,18.62,18.62-8.35,18.62-18.62,18.62Zm0-35.45c-9.28,0-16.83,7.55-16.83,16.83s7.55,16.83,16.83,16.83,16.83-7.55,16.83-16.83-7.55-16.83-16.83-16.83Z"
        fill="#373838" stroke-width="0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Just seeing an example like this is immensely helpful. Fiddling with the numbers teaches me what things are. Reading up on 'keySplines' left me wondering if they were some kind of coordinate thing - but no, they are the rates of acceleration. I wondered where the numbers came from; googled them, and came across https://cubic-bezier.com/#.7,0,.3,1. AHA! Now I understand how this works (though the documentation is still confusing if you don't know what a 'spline' is).